# How to normalize a vector which is combined with other vectors?

Tags: vectors

if  $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2 $ are both $3$ by $1$ matrix ,now i new vector $f_A$

$\vec f_A=\alpha \vec v_1+\beta \vec v_2$,and if i want to normalize the $\vec f_A$ to let $\vec f_A ^T\vec f_A=1$,how do i rewrite the formula

$\vec  n_{f_A}=\frac{\vec f_A}{||\vec f_A||}=\frac{\alpha \vec v_1+\beta \vec v_2}{\sqrt{\alpha^2 \vec v_1^T\vec v_1+\beta^2 \vec v_2 ^T\vec v_2}}?$

Because i found that $\vec  n_{f_A} \vec  n_{f_A}^T \neq 1 ,$so it must be wrong somewhere in my normalization of $\vec f_A$

Comment: Why is $\| f_A \| = \sqrt{\alpha^2v_1^tv_1+\beta^2v_2^tv_2}$?

Comment: @Azif00 because i want to find the length of $f_A$,that is ,the square of the  inner product of $f_A$

Answer (score 0):

It should be $$\hat{\vec {f}}_A=\frac{\vec{f}_A}{\sqrt{(\vec{f}_A)^T \vec{f}_A}},$$
where $T$ denotes transpose. In denominator $v_1^T v_2$ and $v_2^T v_1$ will also be
there. In case, these two are orthogonal these  terms will vanish.